# Open statement according to a file extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to process two types of files in a directory - `.txt` and `.gz`.
There are two types of open statements for this purpose:

**.gz** files:

```
with gzip.open(file_name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = next(f)
    while line:
        some code
```

**.txt** files:

```
with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = next(f)
    while line:
        some code
```

Any further processing commands are absolutely identical. Now I see two options to process these two file types:

**Option 1** - Use two identical functions that differ only by `open` statement. Sounds ugly...

**Option 2** - Use `if` construction as following:

```
if ext == '.gz':
    f = gzip.open(file_name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
elif ext == '.txt':
    f = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

    line = next(f)
    while line:
        some code
```

But it still looks awkward to me :/

**Question**: what's pythonic way in Python 3.x to use open statement according to a file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not:

```
with (gzip.open if ext==".gz" else open)(file_name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

the first argument of `with` is a ternary expression, where you decide which function to use depending on the extension. I used `'rt'` in both cases, it's default for standard `open`. That method has the advantage to avoid copy/paste and to be able to use context manager.

Maybe some generic function could be created with an helper function:

```
def myopen(file_name)
  return (gzip.open if os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]==".gz" else open)(file_name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
```

use like:

```
with myopen(file_name):
```

Comment: Wow... Looks nice! :) Thanks a lot, @Jean-François! Will test it tomorrow morning and if works, accept your answer. Too exhausted already after sleepless weekend... Cheers.

Comment: Why use `lambda` instead of `def` here? The whole point of `lambda` is that you don't have to provide a name, and can embed it in the middle of an expression. But you're putting it on its own statement, and giving it a name (but one that won't be reflected in, e.g., stack traces), so why?

Comment: yes, no need for lambda. it was a oneline function, but not necessary.

Comment: That's... rather a mouthful. Just use `if ext == '.gz': f = gzip.open(file_name, ...)`, etc. then `with f:`. Nothing says you have to create the context manager in the `with` statement.

Comment: You know, if I see code like this in the real world (not SO), I would think it was written by a newbie who finds one-liners impressive. Can we please write code that doesn't require horizontal scroll bars?

Comment: Also, your code relies on the fact that the arguments passed to both `open` functions are the same. What would you do if the arguments are different?

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is to use a `defaultdict` with the extension as key

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

open_functions = defaultdict(lambda: (open, ("r",), {encoding: "utf-8"}))
open_functions["gz"] = (gzip.open, ("rt",), {encoding: "utf-8"})

filename = Path(filename)

open_function, args, kwargs = open_functions[filename.suffix]
with open_function(filename, *args, **kwargs) as f:
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like suggest the following way:

```
#------------------------------------
import zipfile

#-----------------------Common Code-------------------------
def disp_line(filee):    
        for line in filee.readlines():    
            print(line)

#-----------------------First File-----------------------  
z = zipfile.ZipFile('D:\\DC-Data\\baby_names.zip', "r")    
zinfo = z.namelist()    
for name in zinfo:    
    with z.open(name) as filee:    
        disp_line(filee)

#-----------------------2nd File-------------------------            
with open('D:\\DC-Data\\iris.txt', 'r') as filee:
    disp_line(filee) 

#------------------------End ----------------------
```