# python: "with" syntax for opening files with two functions

Tags: python

Let's say I want to open a text file for reading using the following syntax:

```
with open(fname,'r') as f:
    # do something
    pass
```

But if I detect that it ends with .gz, I would call gzip.open().

```
if fname.endswith('.gz'):
    with gzip.open(fname,'rt') as f:
            # do something
            pass
else:
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
            # do something
            pass
```

If "do something" part is long and not convenient to write in a function (e.g. it would create a nested function, which cannot be serialized), what is the shortest way to call with either gzip.open or open based on the return of fname.endswith('.gz')?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224375/open-statement-according-to-a-file-extension . but the answers here are slightly different therefore i think it should remain open and not be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The context manager helps *close* the object.

You don't have to create the object used as a context manager, at the same time you use `with` to enter the context, though. The `open()` and `gzip.open()` calls return a new object that happens to be a context manager, and you can create them before you enter the context:

```
if fname.endswith('.gz'):
    f = gzip.open(fname,'rt')
else:
    f = open(fname, 'r')

with f:
    # do something
```

In both cases, the object returns `self` on entering the context, so there is no need to use `as f` here.

Also, functions are first-class citizens, so you can also use a variable to store the function and then call that in the `with` statement to create the context manager and file object:

```
if fname.endswith('.gz'):
    opener = gzip.open
else:
    opener = open

with opener(fname, 'rt') as f:  # yes, both open and gzip.open support mode='rt'
    # do something
```

This doesn't really buy you anything over the other method here, but you could use a dictionary to map extensions to callables if you so desire.

The bottom line is that `with` [calls context-manager hook methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), nothing less, nothing more. The expression after `with` is supposed to supply such a manager, but *creating* that object is not subject to the context management protocol.

Comment: Thanks! Can you just explain why "opener, mode = open"? How is it possible that "opener = open" wouldn't work?

Comment: @CindyAlmighty: that was an editing error, sorry. I originally assigned both an opener and a mode (so `opener, mode = gzip.open, 'rt'`), but then realised that `open()` accepts `rt` to mean the same thing as `r` for the mode.

Answer (score 9):

You can bind either context manager to the same name and choose early:

```
if fname.endswith('.gz'):
    context = gzip.open(fname,'rt')
else:
    context = open(fname,'r')

with context as f:
    # do the same thing in either case
```

This allows for some nice patterns, for instance if the input is possibly an opened file handle then you could use [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) to get a no-op in the `with` block for the given case.

Comment: It's one of the beautiful things about Python because everything is an object you can get away with lots of neat tricks like this.  Another favorite of mine is using `dict`s as a switch.

Comment: 1. can you explain the last sentence please? :)
2. @Idlehands What is this use of dict as a switch?

Comment: Here's an answer that utilizes the `dict` object as a switch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python#60211

Comment: @CindyAlmighty it isn't directly applicable to your use case. But imagine the scenario when you have "_My `fname` is either a file path that needs to be opened or it has already been opened elsewhere by `open(the_actual_file_name)`_". In this case you could do, say `context = gzip.open(fname, 'rt') if isinstance(fname, str) else contextlib.nullcontext(fname)` and use a single `with context as f:` block which will work in both cases just fine. This is exactly the second example given [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext), actually.

Comment: @Idlehands.  very true, and Python is usually pretty clear in its intent. but context managers _are_ a bit unusual in their implicit enter/exit triggering.   It’s not all that obvious that the context creation can syntactically be separated from **as**, so this post is extra informative - despite using them for a while this is a new trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
with gzip.open(fname, 'rt') if fname.endswith('.gz') else open(fname, 'r') as f:
    # do something
    pass
```

Comment: Why the need to put everything on one line?

Comment: No real need of course, which is your (valid) point. But arguably it answers the actual question better, as the question mentions: "[...] what is the shortest way [...]"

Comment: I did not say that. It was the OP who asked that.

Comment: I didn't say you said that.

Comment: Although this is not as useful, it truly is what I asked. And also shows another possibility!
A great answer IMHO.

Comment: exactly my original proposal btw :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224375/open-statement-according-to-a-file-extension